# jQuery Masonry Plugin on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8, jquery-masonry

I am using jQuery masonry plugin in my project and everything is running properly on newer version of browsers. However, when I try to run it on IE8, I got this error and it did not functioning properly:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Fri, 15 Nov 2013 09:00:45 UTC

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 9
Char: 8948
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js
```

How can I solve it? If really can't get it works, is there any other alternative way to do it with IE8 support?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) (IE7.js, an IE compatibility library) and report back.

Comment: Doesn't seems helping, but bring more trouble.